# Generating a boolean mask indexing one array into another array

Tags: numpy, pandas

It's hard to explain what I'm trying to do with words so here's an example.

Let's say we have the following inputs:

```
In [76]: x
Out[76]: 
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    a
4    b

In [77]: z
Out[77]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I want to get:

```
In [78]: ii
Out[78]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`ii` is an array of boolean masks which can be applied to `z` to get back the original `x`.

My current solution is to write a function which converts `z` to a `list` and uses the `index` method to get the index of the element in `z` and then generate a row of zeroes except for the index where there is a one. This function gets applied to each row of `x` to get the desired result.

Comment: And so, what's your question? Writing this function? Surely, something like `np.choose(["abcde".index(i) for i in x], "abcde")` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Well, I get `array(['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], dtype='|S1')` as a result when I run your line. What I want is the masks (lists of 5 boolean elements) for `['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b']`. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Are you looking for a faster way or just somthing shorter to type like: np.array([[j == i for j in z] for i in x], dtype=int)

Comment: @WouterOvermeire looking for both ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first possibility:

```
>>> choices = np.diag([1]*5)
>>> choices[[z.index(i) for i in x]]
```

As noted elsewhere, you can change the list comprehension `[z.index(i) for i in x]` by `np.searchsorted(z, x)`

```
>>> choices[np.searchsorted(z, x)]
```

Note that as suggested in a comment by [@seberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455221/seberg), you should use `np.eye(len(x))` instead of `np.diag([1]*len(x))`. The `np.eye` function directly gives you a 2D array with 1 on the diagonal and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: The first one is what I was looking for.

Comment: Instead of `np.diag([1]*5)`, rather use `np.eye(5)` I think.

Answer (score 1):

This is numpy method for the case of z being sorted. You did not specifiy that... If pandas needs something differently, I don't know:

```
# Assuming z is sorted.
indices = np.searchsorted(z, x)
```

Now I really don't know why you want a boolean mask, these indices can be applied to z to give back x already and are more compact.

```
z[indices] == x # if z included all x.
```

Comment: Unfortunately they are not sorted, my example is misleading. Also I need the masks because I multiply them by some probability matrix after that: https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow/forums/t/2644/multi-class-log-loss-function

Comment: If they are unique, sort them yourself first, if you care about speed. As to creation of the boolean array, I would suggest something like `a = np.zeros((...,...), dtype=bool); a[np.ix_[np.arange(...), z]] = 1` maybe. But doesn't matter much.

Comment: If I sort them then I'll have to sort the columns of all the other arrays and matrices that I have to match. Not sure if it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one mentioned the`outer` method of `numpy.equal`:

```
In [51]: np.equal.outer(s, z)
Out[51]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [52]: np.equal.outer(s, z).astype(int)
Out[52]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```